# Does a continuous function map a closed set to closed set?

Tags: calculus, analysis

True or False?: If D is closed and f is continuous, then f(D) is closed.

The answer is false. However, i can prove that it is true and i can't find what i did wrong.

Here's my proof: Whenever $x_k$ is a sequence in D with $x_k \rightarrow x$, we have that $x \in D$ since D is closed. Also, since f is continuous on D, it follows that $f(x_k) \rightarrow f(x)$ and $f(x) \in f(D)$ because $x \in D$. which implies that f(D) is closed.

Which step is wrong?

question added: If D is open, then f(D) is open. true or false?

Comment: It's possible to have continuous function $f$ and sequence $(x_n)$ such that $(x_n)$ does not converge, but $(f(x_n))$ does converge.

Comment: Think of $\arctan(x)$ - it maps $\mathbb{R}$, a closed set, to $(\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Comment: As an even simpler example, think of the inclusion function $(-1, 1) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous but not closed.

Comment: @Chris but it is not $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ closed in the same way that it is $\Bbb R$? As a topological subsapce of $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you started with a sequence in D instead of $f(D)$.

To show $f(D)$ is closed. Let $f(x_n)$ be a sequence in $f(D)$ such that $f(x_n) \to x$. You now need to prove that $x \in f(D)$.

You can't prove this because it isn't true.